# linq query with a list in the where clause

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2012

I have a linq query written in the below format. Now when I am passing a consumerID it works fine and I am able to put it in the where clause. However when I try to pass a list of consumerIds, how can I put this in the where clause. I have looked through some solution online and they all use some other linq format which I dont want to use. 
Please suggesest if I can have a list in the where clause, something similar to how we can have in clause in sql??

```
public ICollection<ConsumerExchangeChangeDto> GetByConsumers(List<int> consumerIDs)
{
    EnrollmentReportingModel db = (EnrollmentReportingModel)Context.DbContext;
    var results = (from ecew in db.A
        join ecewe in db.B on ecew.ID 
        equals ecewe.ExchangeChangeEnrollmentWindowID into temp
        from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join cecr in db.C on ecew.ConsumerExchangeChangeRequestID equals cecr.ID
        join con in db.D on cecr.ConsumerID equals con.ID
        where con.ID.Contains(consumerIDs) && !ecew.Deleted
        select new E
        {
            ConsumerID = con.ID,
            OrganizationID = con.OrganizationID,
            StartDate = ecew.StartDate,
            EndDate = ecew.EndDate,
            Deleted = ecew.Deleted
        }).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Here is  the dto class

```
public class E : ILzDto
{
    public int ConsumerID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
where con.ID.Contains(consumerIDs)
```

to this:

```
where consumerIDs.Contains(con.ID)
```

This will check if the id of the items in the select statement are in the input list.

Comment: thanks for that response. Can you suggest if I change my function defintion to public ICollection<ConsumerExchangeChangeDto> GetByConsumers(int[] consumerIDs)

Comment: @kushalbhola I'm not sure what you mean. Why would you want to pass an array rather than a list?

Comment: I am getting these ids from an external api, I could convert it into a list and work off, but why to do it if I can just modify my function definition

Comment: @kushalbhola - ah. Yes you can pass an array if that's what you have.

Comment: I was looking for how I can still use the array with the contain piece of the code. Anyways I converted the array to list and working off it

Comment: @kushal - you have to have a list if you want to use the data in a linq query.

Comment: thanks ChrisF for all your help anyways. i have it figured out

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work all the time. So I am calling GetByConsumers with 100 consumerID array, and the contains only checks for one ID against 100 items in consumerIDs. So the final result set contains only 1 entry. Do you see what I am saying? I can repost with more verbose code if that helps

Comment: Essentially when I am passing 100 consumerIDs, it should lookup all it can find in db, but in this case it just looks up for 1 guy and gives up

Comment: @kushalbhola - what I've presented should return you all customers who's Ids are in the array/list you pass in. Perhaps you need to ask a **new** question as to why your modified code doesn't work.